# Save image to Sql Server image to image field using C# and Subsonic

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, subsonic2.2

In an ASP.NET app (using framework 2.0), and the ORM for this application is Subsonic 2.2, which I'm working with for the first time.

I have an image which I've retrieved from a URL, and I have an HttpWebresponse object, which I've converted to an image, like this:

```
    string uri = ...;
    HttpWebRequest lxRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
    HttpWebResponse lxResponse = (HttpWebResponse) lxRequest.GetResponse();
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(lxResponse.GetResponseStream());
```

In Sql Server, I've created an Image column (could be any other binary format, that's not a problem), and I'd like to write my image into it. I'd also like to know how to read from the column, so as to test that the image has been correctly saved.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Image is a depreciated datatype in SQL Server so you may want to change your datatype in the database to varbinary(max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `image` column, Subsonic creates a `byte[]` property.

Therefore, you'll have to transform your data (`System.Drawing.Image` in this case) *to* and *from* a byte array.

[Other](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ImageConverter.aspx) [sites](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/PrintSearchContent.asp?LINKID=799) have this covered, shamelessly copied:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 return  ms.ToArray();
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have looked at [Read and write SQL image data](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_read-write-sql-image-file/), this might help you

Comment: Thanks for the link, but my data is not in binary format, and I'm not using an ADO.NET connection.